# How to remove all xml children with a given element name in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How to remove all xml children with a given element name in PHP with SimpleXML?

```
<xml>
<computer></computer>
<book></book>
<book></book>
</xml>
```

I need a quick way to remove all "book" elements. Thanks!

Comment: Try yourself first, please. If you're stuck somewhere, come back with that specific question.

Comment: No, I would like to use simple xml actually

Comment: YOu cannot (I repeat: cannot) remove nodes (or rearrange the document tree) with SimpleXML. (well, you can just `unset`a node you selected, but it only works for single nodes.) It doesn'T have any remove methods.

Answer (score 0):

select all  nodes with `xpath` and `unset` them:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

$books = $xml->xpath("//book");
foreach ($books as $book) unset($book[0]);
```

see it in action: https://eval.in/105257